# Need identification on this growth on cherry & possibly plum trees and possible remedies

Tags: diseases, fungus, cherries, plums, permaculture

It's what I like to call

[image: The Alien Fungus]

The Alien Fungus,

the plants don't seem to be happy about it, but they do give fruit - it grows in continental Croatia, Europe, typical yearly temperature range -20 to 40 and high humidity with heavy clay (surrounded by an old forrest).

Some of the affected trees are a bit weak and tend to fall under the snow more often, they do give fruit but not as much as one would expect.

I'm also looking for a remedy for this, if possible (as much as is possible):

1. non-toxic
2. natural
3. can be applied during fruiting/flowering

**UPDATE** [this good answer seems to have ID-ed the brown thing](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/39065/16825) and that it feeds on dead wood (ie wood already dead)- but it seems now that the blueish-whiteish growth is a separate growth and is possibly killing the wood, does someone recognize it?

**UPDATE** the same answer as above ID-ed the blue-white thing as lichen - not harmful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like chocolate slime mold... Seriously... Also known as [*Stemonitopsis*](https://hiveminer.com/Tags/stemonitidaceae,stemonitis). It is normally feeding on dead trees, so I don't think it is causing your tree problems. If parts of your trees are dead (which they feed on) it has probably another cause.

Comment: Good point! And good id it seems! Funny enough, the growth is on the main trunk, and the trees give fruit. Is it possible it's two beings, one killing, one eating what dies? The blue  The Stemonitis & the whitish-bluish growth?

Comment: The blue things on the bark you mean? They are Lichen, and are a good sign (of unpolluted and healthy air). They are no harm for your tree, but they are slow growers so they indicate that your trees are old... Do you know how old they are?

Comment: Good, thank you. Quite old, possibly 15 years, maybe 20, maybe it's just old age?

Comment: Yeah maybe old age, or something invisible (fungus?) inside. But the Lichen are not harmful for your tree.